# I am trying to get the sum of values from my "price" node in the firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, integer

The app is building without an error, but when running it gives the following error in the logcat:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference at com.bwae.kuja.Main2Activity.onDataChange.

I also received the warning:

> unboxing of 'ds.child("Price).getValue(Integer.class) may produce java.lang.NullPointerException.

I am new to the use of Integers, so please and kindly assist me with the necessary edit I should make to my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    mda = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = mda.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                int pvalue = ds.child("Price").getValue(Integer.class);
                sum += pvalue;
                if (sum < 100) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());

        }
    });
```

THE picture below is a view of my database. I am trying to get the total values of the figures under price, for example 99+66

[image: THE picture below is a view of my database. I am trying to get the total values of the figures under price, for example 99+66]

Once the total is calculated from the child (price) in the database if the total is less than 100, I should receive a toast message saying success.

Comment: Please update your question to include the code of what you attach the listener to. Right now we have to way to know what `dataSnapshot` contains.

Comment: I have updated it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot of your data it seems like you have a space character after `Price`, so `"Price "`. Here's how property names `Price` and `Price` show up in the Firebase console:

[image]

You can either fix this mistake in your data, or update the code to read the value from the correct property:

```
int pvalue = ds.child("Price ").getValue(Integer.class);
```